# I want to send my url as a plain data to java server from php file

Tags: java, php, curl

Here Is my code. 2nd variable contain my url which i want to send to remote server.anyone can help me?

```
<?php
$URLTOPOST="Here is my URL. where i send my data";
$DATATOPOST="http://localhost/newc/index.php";
$data=urlencode($DATATOPOST);
$ch=curl_init($URLTOPOST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata=curl_exec($ch);
echo $returndata;
curl_close($returndata);
?>
```

Comment: U have to wrap it like a querystring : URL=your URL. This way it will work

Comment: see this http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post and change your data like query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either build a query string   likes this

```
 **http://www.yoururl.com?data=123&data1=xyz**
```

or you can use CURL set option to send Post Data  like this

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.yoururl.com/index.php");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
  "var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3");
```